# Avoid RecordNotFound exception with friendly_id gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

Is there a way to have `friendly.find` simply return `nil` when the slug isn't available in any record, rather than raise the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/lib/friendly_id/finder_methods.rb#L37) for the `friendly_id` finders it doesn't appear to be configurable.

```
def find_by_friendly_id(id)
  first_by_friendly_id(id) or raise raise_not_found_exception(id)
end
```

You can always do basic Rails lookup with

```
Model.find_by(slug: 'some-nice-slug')
```